# SumProduct Function with Criteria from Different Locations Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, sumproduct

**Updated:**

Taking into consideration community comments, I have made some changes (*declarations, removed unnecessary variables*) and attempted two styles to no avail.

Without criteria the code returns 400, after one line is populated.

```
.Cells(i, 38 + l) = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(" & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn & "," & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn & ",--(" & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(4).EntireColumn & "=" & .Cells(i, 2).Value & "),--(" & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(5).EntireColumn & "=" & .Cells(i, 3).Value & "))")
```

And also:

```
.Cells(i, 38 + l) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn, Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(83 + l * 4).EntireColumn, --(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(4).EntireColumn = .Cells(i, 2).Value), --(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(5).EntireColumn = .Cells(i, 3).Value))
```

**/Update end.**

I have been trying to code a macro, which will gather data from different worksheets of one workbook to summary sheet and perform necessary calculations ("sumifs", "sumproduct") in cycle. The same code will be used in the other workbooks with different variable parameters.

While "sumifs" is  working fine, there is an issue with "sumproduct" function (I am using *Application.WorksheetFunction* instead of *Evaluate*).

The code returns Type Mismatch error. Most likely I am calling the function improperly, OR, the criteria within the function.

I am kindly asking for community support, as I feel, I have exhausted my ability to think today.

```
' Populate table from KA sheets for I/O to SOP Report

Dim EndRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim catLst As Range
Dim pglst As Range

Start:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set pglst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY").Range("$D:$D")
Set catLst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY").Range("$E:$E")

For i = 4 To EndRow
For j = 0 To 24
For l = 0 To 6
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IO")
        .Cells(i, 4 + j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(54 + j).EntireColumn, pglst, .Cells(i, 2).Value, catLst, .Cells(i, 3).Value)
        .Cells(i, 30 + l) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn, pglst, .Cells(i, 2).Value, catLst, .Cells(i, 3).Value)
        .Cells(i, 38 + l) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn, Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(83 + l * 4).EntireColumn, --(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(4).EntireColumn = .Cells(i, 2).Value), --(Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(5).EntireColumn = .Cells(i, 3).Value))
'        .Cells(i, 38 + l) = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(" & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn & "," & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(81 + l * 4).EntireColumn & ",--(" & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(4).EntireColumn & "=" & .Cells(i, 2).Value & "),--(" & Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Columns(5).EntireColumn & "=" & .Cells(i, 3).Value & "))")
    End With
Next l
Next j
Next i

'Set i = Nothing
'Set j = Nothing
'Set l = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IO").Range("AS1") = "UPDATED: " & Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM")

Finish:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: At a first glance, I don't think `Set condPG = Evaluate("=--(pglst="".Cells(i, 2).Value"")")` is going to work. Same for `condCAT`. `Evaluate` does not execute code-as-a-string. And it's unclear why you're using `Set` or `Range` here.

Comment: You can't `Evaluate` text-that-looks-like-VBA.

Comment: It was used to make the line third line of cycle shorter (took it this from Mr.Excel forum post), regardless, it did not work, even when conditions were put inline, where supposed to. `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct( ...code-code-code...,--(pglst=.Cells(i, 2).Value), --(catlst=.Cells(i, 3).Value)))` I have also tried to modify the code (see updates in the original post), however, I still miss something.

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

```
Dim catLst, pglst, condPG, condCAT As Range
```

only `condCAT` is declared as Range the rest is declared as Variant.
(Same with your long declaration)

Like BigBen wrote, it is unclear what you are doing with this evaluate.
You should not use Evaluate

Set for every part in your SumProduct a range. So that your Sumproduct would be like

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(range1,range2,...)
```

And look, if every range has the same size. SumProduct is a matrix function.
E.G. Range("A1:A5") Range("B1:B3") could not work in Sumproduct because of Elements

But I guess, some parts of your SumProduct are just wrong type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have cleaned up a little bit (see updates in the original post), however the error persists, I believe it has something to do with the syntax for criteria, or, as you mentioned in the comment, the matrix function cannot be called within loop (have I understood that right?). The ranges are the same length.

Comment: `.Cells(i, 38 + l) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Worksheets(Cells` seems strange to me, because `Worksheets(Cells` will take the active sheet and not the sheet you have in your with clause. Are you missing some dots? And still you should set every range extra in for your SumProduct , then you can check more easily if they have the correct range. And Start perhaps only with two ranges and so on. Keep ist simple!

Comment: `Worksheets(Cells(i, 1).Value)` calls the source sheet name (which is in the column 1 of the summary sheet in every row till the end of list) to use in the formula. it works fine with _SumIfs_. I have tried to use the _SumProduct_ without criteria, it works, but returns 400 after one line of calculation. So the problem in my code is a combination of proper use of function and criteria call. Which is a problem, I cannot define, therefore -- solve.